# What is default javac source mode (assert as identifier compilation)?

Tags: java, compilation, assert

According to Orcale's [Java7 assert guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html#enable-disable):

> - source mode 1.3 (default) — the compiler accepts programs that use assert as an identifier, but issues warnings. In this mode, programs are not permitted to use the assert statement.
> - source mode 1.4 — the compiler generates an error message if the program uses assert as an identifier. In this mode, programs are permitted to use the assert statement.

I wrote such class:

```
package mm;

public class ClassTest {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        int assert = 1;
        System.out.println(assert);
    }
}
```

It should compile fine if Oracle's info right (1.3 is default source mode). But I got errors like this:

```
$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_04

$ javac -d bin src/mm/*
src\mm\ClassTest.java:5: error: as of release 1.4, 'assert' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
                int assert = 1;
                    ^
  (use -source 1.3 or lower to use 'assert' as an identifier)
src\mm\ClassTest.java:6: error: as of release 1.4, 'assert' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
                System.out.println(assert);
                                   ^
  (use -source 1.3 or lower to use 'assert' as an identifier)
2 errors
```

I added manually `-source 1.3` and it issued warnings but compiled fine. It seems that Oracle's information is wrong and 1.3 is not default source mode. Which one is it then?

Comment: I think you've answered your own question ;)

Comment: its probably not a good idea to use assert as an identifier, whatever the situation.

Comment: @Guillaume: I only know it is not 1.3, but which one is it? I mean there are only two options? Or you can chose 1.4, 1.5, 1.6 or 1.7?

Comment: @NimChimpsky: Yes I know, I made it only for practice and for research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java 7, the default source mode is 1.7 [according to Oracle's doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#options) (see the -source option).
The doc you're referring to probably needs to be updated